# EXCEL import with some additional columns - won't import

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to import some data into my table (SQL SERVER) - thats easy, but I have a few more columns that are appended to the end, and not in the XLS. I cant just go an add them on to the XLS as this is an automated task that I need to make happen on a weekly basis.

So I tried within the import itself and looking at the select it actually puts them at the front of the query so for example

It will bring back Contact, comments, * (rest of the rows), if I could swap this order around I am sure this would work. Is there anyway I can do this?

```
 insert into BusinessSignups 
   select * from openrowset
      (
      'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
      'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Oracle\Business-Support-Signups\result1.xls', 
      'SELECT *, 0 as contact,null as comments FROM [result$]'
       )t
        where not exists 
         (select 1
          from BusinessSignups
           where BusinessSignups.week = t.week
           and BusinessSignups.year = t.year
           and BusinessSignups.account_id = t.account_id
          ) 
      go
```

Comment: Move the added columns to the `select * from openrowset` line?

Comment: hahaha its the simple things - rockstar. Case closed!